# Can't Sprite using gulp.spritesmith

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-spritesmith

**Showing Error when I sprite,**

I an new in gulp sprite, I need help,

this the error showing my console

```
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    sass\custom\_sprite.scss
Error: index out of bounds for `nth($list, $n)`
        on line 421 of sass/custom/_sprite.scss
>>   width: nth($sprite, 5);

[12:50:49] Finished 'sass' after 507 ms
```

**This is my include**

I imported _sprite.scss in my scss file and Included Like this.

```
.jaba {
    i {
        @include sprite-width('facebook.png');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The sprite mixin expects a spritesmith generated variable, not a string.

```
.jaba {
    i {
        @include sprite-width($facebook);
    }
}
```